# NgINX error_page

Tags: nginx

I have some virtual host configurated on my server.
I Need to set a common error_page for all them.

**host1.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name host1.com

    root host1/path;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:xxxx;
    }
}
```

**host2.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name host2.com

    root host2/path;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:xxxx;
    }
}
```

and so on.

**1) Could I set the error_page in every .conf file?**

Could I set the error_page in every .conf file? Or I'm able to set it only in a default .conf?

**2) Problem with error redirect**

I have a 404.html page and 50x.html page too on my default server.
So I added the  follow instructions to all my host .conf files

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root /path/to/default;
}
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /path/to/default;
}
```

I see rightly that page but... they have some css, webfonts and images inclusion. That inclusions are not resolved, it seems they are looked on host root instead of default root.

There is a solution for have a single error page setted on a default site configuration and reused in all others conf?

Comment: If your `error_page` uses an absolute URL, you can get away with putting it in the `http` container and letting each `server` block inherit. Otherwise, you will need `location` blocks in each `server` and maybe using `include` is the simplest solution.

Comment: Use include is a good suggestion. The error page has an absolute URL but  it should not be displayed.